# if $B$ is orthonormal basis for $V$ so $f(B)$ is also orthonormal basis for $V$? (f is orthogonal)

Tags: linear-algebra

How to prove this:
Consider  $f:V\to V$ **orthogonal** transform.
let $u_{1},u_2\dots,u_n$ be orthonormal basis for $V$.
so $f\left(u_1\right),f\left(u_2\right)\dots f\left(u_n\right)$ is also orthonormal basis for $V$.
Well i know i need to show that $V\:=\text{span}\left(f\left(u_1\right),f\left(u_2\right)\dots f\left(u_n\right)\right)\:$ & that $\left(f\left(u_1\right),\:f\left(u_2\right),\dots f\left(u_n\right)\right)$ are independent, but i struggle in each of these conditions.

Can someone guide me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: orthogonal transformations preserve vector norms and also orthogonality between vectors; what can you say of a set of nonzero pairwise orthogonal vectors?

Comment: ok and what about that i need to show V=span(f(u1),f(u2)…f(un))?